# Conditional in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, conditional-statements

I've got multiple elements in the list and I would like make a conditional to change such values by icons

In google console: `$('li #valorar');`

Shows:

```
[
  <span id=​"valorar">​4​</span>​
 , 
  <span id=​"valorar">​1​</span>​
 , 
  <span id=​"valorar">​5​</span>​
]
```

And my conditional:

```
var valoraciond = $('li #valorar').html();

    if (valoraciond == 0) {
     $('li #valorar').replaceWith('<span style="color:#fff" class="icon star-empty"></span><span style="color:#fff" class="icon star-empty"></span><span style="color:#fff" class="icon star-empty"></span><span style="color:#fff" class="icon star-empty"></span><span style="color:#fff" class="icon star-empty"></span>');
    }else if (valoraciond == 1) {
     $('li #valorar').replaceWith('<span style="color:#fff" class="icon star"></span><span style="color:#fff" class="icon star-empty"></span><span style="color:#fff" class="icon star-empty"></span><span style="color:#fff" class="icon star-empty"></span><span style="color:#fff" class="icon star-empty"></span>');
    }else if (valoraciond == 2) {
     $('li #valorar').replaceWith('<span style="color:#fff" class="icon star"></span><span style="color:#fff" class="icon star"></span><span style="color:#fff" class="icon star-empty"></span><span style="color:#fff" class="icon star-empty"></span><span style="color:#fff" class="icon star-empty"></span>');
    }else if (valoraciond == 3) {
     $('li #valorar').replaceWith('<span style="color:#fff" class="icon star"></span><span style="color:#fff" class="icon star"></span><span style="color:#fff" class="icon star"></span><span style="color:#fff" class="icon star-empty"></span><span style="color:#fff" class="icon star-empty"></span>');
    }else if (valoraciond == 4) {
     $('li #valorar').replaceWith('<span style="color:#fff" class="icon star"></span><span style="color:#fff" class="icon star"></span><span style="color:#fff" class="icon star"></span><span style="color:#fff" class="icon star"></span><span style="color:#fff" class="icon star-empty"></span>');
    }else if (valoraciond == 5) {
     $('li #valorar').replaceWith('<span style="color:#fff" class="icon star"></span><span style="color:#fff" class="icon star"></span><span style="color:#fff" class="icon star"></span><span style="color:#fff" class="icon star"></span><span style="color:#fff" class="icon star"></span>')
    }else{
    }
```

Why only take the first element?How I can get all items? Sorry for my english

Comment: IDs must be unique, right?

Comment: yes, Ids are unique. And HTML code: <li><span id="valorar">1></span><span id="valorar">2></span><span id="valorar">3></span><span id="valorar">4></span></li>

Comment: So why is your selector 'li #valorar' when '#valorar' is enough?

Comment: as @undefined stated IDs must be unique, so change id to class

Comment: When ID's are not unique, a query only returns the first element that matches.

Comment: Please start using `switch` instead of so many `if else` statements.

Comment: You could do this better by removing the if else and use a css class instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commentors have it right: the problem is you're using IDs, and IDs are supposed to be unique.  If your IDs aren't unique, you have invalid HTML, and you can't expect jQuery to handle that magically.

As an aside, your code is not very DRY.  All that repeated HTML!  It can all be replaced by the following:

```
$('li.valorar').each(function(){
    var stars = Number( $(this).html() );
    var html = '';
    // TODO: error handling if stars is not a number
    // add stars
    for( var i=0; i<stars; i++ ) {
        html += '<span style="color:#fff" class="icon star"></span>';
    }
    // add empty stars
    for( ; i<5; i++ ) {
        html += '<span style="color:#fff" class="icon star-empty"></span>';
    }
    $(this).html( html );
});
```

You can see it in action in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WJ9vp/1/